# Apache Santuario for signing does not add SecurityTokenReference under KeyInfo

Tags: xml-signature

Lines of code for adding Keyinfo in my code looks like :

```
sig.addKeyInfo(cert);
logUtil.debug("Start signing");
sig.sign(privateKey);
logUtil.debug("Finished signing");
```

This gives a key info element like :

```
<ds:KeyInfo>
                    <ds:X509Data>
                        <ds:X509Certificate>
xxx certificate value xxx
                        </ds:X509Certificate>
                    </ds:X509Data>

</ds:KeyInfo>
```

But the requirement is to have the X509Data element inside SecurityTokenReference element.

Any views on how to do it with apache santuario / org apache xml security signature is much appreciated.

Comment: It would help others help you if you gave a minimal complete example program.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the comments . A sample example would be same as this link http://pushpalankajaya.blogspot.nl/2014/03/signing-soap-messages-generation-of.html .